# Using git for approval process?

Tags: git, github, release-management

I work in a regulated environment where software changes need specific sign-offs by specific people or roles.  Currently this is using git for version control, and tracking approvals outside of git.

I would like to see if there is a way to do approvals in git.  If there is a solution which is github-only (based on github forking and pull requests from forks, or github code reviews etc) that would be interesting as well.

The specific elements needed are:

- *Who* approved something should be easy to find out (git log) and provable, in a way equivalent to a Docusign or electronic signature.  Signing with a code signing key for example would work.
- Each piece of code may need to be approved by more than one person (there could be a per-project list, or on a case-by-case basis)
- It is very desirable to be able to approve a larger changeset (pull request, branch merge etc) at once rather than just a single commit.
- It is desirable but not essential to be able to prevent some actions (merge to master / make release tag etc) unless the right approvals are in place.

I know that git has a signed-off-by feature, can this be used for what I described?

**EDIT** Thanks for all the answers... From the direction of some of them, it looks like I should clarify a bit.  My goal is mainly to easily collect info about who approved what when (and also more detailed info from code reviews), rather than to automatically enforce policies (although that is nice too). In this case all contributors are within the same organization and can be assumed to be trusted and to (in general) do the right things.  It's just that the process now is manual, very slow and somewhat error prone.  To give you an idea: for every pull request, we create a couple of MS Word docs and put them in Docusign for signatures...

Comment: Have a look at bitbucket also -- it has a lot of those control features.

Comment: @DavidAldridge Thank you, I will. You can post that as an answer if you'd like, and maybe you could provide a bit more detail about how it works

Answer (score 2):

[PullApprove](https://about.pullapprove.com/) is a service that allows pull requests to be blocked until they are reviewed and approved by the relevant people. It only works for  Github repos, but it seems to satisfy all your requirements. PullApprove approvals are given by leaving a comment in the comment thread corresponding to the pull request, so it will leave a record there.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [GitHub protected branches](https://help.github.com/articles/about-protected-branches/) to achieve part of this:

> A protected branch:
>
> - Can't have changes merged into it until required status checks pass
> - Can't have changes merged into it until required reviews are approved

Configure them in the [repo’s settings under branches](https://help.github.com/articles/configuring-protected-branches/).

But there’s no direct facility for signing commits in GitHub, and nothing to enforce that commits are signed, unfortunately.

Comment: Since GitHub made it so that you can just [dismiss required reviews](https://github.com/blog/2265-dismissing-reviews-on-pull-requests) and merge your pull anyway, I'm not sure this method would pass a thorough vetting....

Comment: @Yawar Interesting, though it implies that it only stops that person’s rejection from blocking it, still requiring someone else to approve it. Not sure, though, as I haven’t tested it.

Answer (score 2):

From what you describe, this sounds like a use case for the 'dictator and lieutenant' workflow: https://git-scm.com/book/it/v2/Distributed-Git-Distributed-Workflows#Dictator-and-Lieutenants-Workflow

This workflow is actually used by Linus Torvalds (the 'dictator') and his trusted 'lieutenants' (the kernel subsystem maintainers) to implement a hierarchical project structure. So as you can imagine, it's not specific to GitHub--it's purely based on the use of multiple git forks of the project, each fork maintained by one person responsible for it.

Here's how it would work with your requirements:

- *Who* approved something is a matter of who has it in their fork. If they have it, that means they pulled it and therefore approved it.
- For multiple approvals (levels of the hierarchy), the first approver pulls it and publishes it on their fork; then the next approver pulls from the first approver's fork and publishes on *their own* fork; and so on.
- This technique is mainly used with pull requests (i.e. branches), so this point is automatically covered.
- You would, by agreement, 'bless' the dictator's repo as the 'master' or the canonical repo and anything there would automatically be understood to have passed all the required approvals. The blessed repo maintainer would only pull from the lieutenants' repos and no one else's, thus automatically enforcing the approvals process.

I highly recommend you paper-and-pencil this out with the people (or roles) you have in mind; just make the mental association that one person corresponds to one fork of the repo.

Comment: You are assuming that all the "roles" are programmers hence able to use git and compile the software etc.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same requirements and understand your use case. My company is also developing software in a regulated environment (medical devices). I am exploring implementing a git-based sign-off process for documents and source code that we version-control in using Git. Here is how I am planning to do it. I have the caveat that this workflow will only work for the repository as a whole, but perhaps you could think of how to adapt it for individual sections of code as per your requirements.

- Firstly all people responsible for approving documents should set up [GPG signatures on all of their commits](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Signing-Your-Work). Ideally everyone in the team should do this. This doesn't meant that team members are "signing off" when they make a commit, just that they are signing every commit they make.
- Keep a CHANGELOG.md file in the root of the repository that follows the conventions listed here: https://keepachangelog.com/en/1.0.0/.
- Before each release is made, the CHANGELOG.md entry for that release is drafted in the `Unreleased` section.
- In addition to the sections that keepachangelog recommend (`Added`, `Changed`, `Deprecated` etc), add a `Signed` section. This section should be templated with a list of the individuals that need to sign off on the release and which role they are signing off. For instance:

  ```
  ### Signed

  | Role           | Team Member      | Signed |
  | :------------- | :----------      | :----- |
  | Product Owner  | Joe Placeholder  |        |
  | Technical Lead | Jane Example     |        |
  ...
  ```
- Prior to the release, each of the people listed in the Signed section reviews the release and when they are happy, adds their initials to the `Signed` column. E.g.:

  ```
  ### Signed
  | Role           | Team Member      | Signed |
  | :------------- | :----------      | :----- |
  | Product Owner  | Joe Placeholder  |        |
  | Technical Lead | Jane Example     | JE     |
  …
  ```
- The initials don't really prove anything, but do provide a quick human readable checklist of who has and hasn't signed off on a release. However, the team member who added their initials then commits their changes to CHANGELOG.md with a commit message `Sign off release vX.X.X`. Because every commit is signed with GPG, their is cryptographic proof that the signatory did actually sign off on the release.
- Once the release has been drafted, reviewed and signed by everyone responsible, the repository admin can then bump the version number and tag the release. Bonus points if the admin also signs the tag using their GPG key.

So that is how we will implement this process. Here are some ways of doing it I also considered:

- The obvious one is to use Github/Gitlab Pull Requests and protected branches to prevent merging to master, or a "Released" branch without a review.

  - Pros:

    - a workflow that developers already understand,
    - well supported by tools like Github.
    - tools like [LGTM](https://github.com/lgtmco/lgtm) can help when multiple sign-off is required
  - Cons:

    - Not portable outside of Github or Gitlab if you decide to switch Git tools.
    - Not possible to cryptographically sign-off using a GPG key, although being logged in to Github is an equivalent form of proof.
    - Not clear in what capacity someone is signing off in (e.g. `Product Lead`) without extra work/notation. This is a regulatory requirement in my field.
    - Hard to see who has and hasn't signed off without a lot of scrolling up and down the pull-request comments.
- I also looked at using GitHub's Releases tool in place of a CHANGELOG.md to record release notes and people's signatures, but there is no way to provide a proof of signature. Also not portable outside of Github.
- Using the 'dictator and lieutenant' workflow mentioned by @Yawar. This looks good for open-source projects, but when working in private repositories, Github does not allow multiple forks of the same repository. Therefore it not possible to implement if you are using Github private repos. It might be possible to implement something similar by having multiple branches in the same repo with different 'lieutenants' responsible for each branch. These 'lieutenants' then sign off by accepting pull requests from their sub-teams into their branch before making pull-requests to the 'dictator's' branch. However: having experimented with complex branching workflows like [Git Flow](https://datasift.github.io/gitflow/IntroducingGitFlow.html) in the past, it has been very difficult to implement smoothly and so I would be very skeptical of implementing a workflow any more complicated than integrating all pull-requests into a single `Master` branch.